# Python: why doesn't my string return or print when I run my code

Tags: python, input

```
def the_flying_circus(Question = raw_input("Do you like the Flying Circus?")):
    if Question == 'yes':
        print "That's great!" 
    elif Question == 'no':
        print "That's too bad!"
```

I am trying to get the if expression to run the code and return either string based on the raw input. Everytime I run it, the question prompts but then when I attempt to input 'yes or no' it gives me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ftidocreview\Desktop\ex.py", line 1, in <module>
    def the_flying_circus(Question = input("Do you like the Flying Circus?")):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: You're not running the same code you gave.

Comment: @MxyL: yes, really.  Compare the `raw_input` in the first line of the code to the `input` in the traceback.

Answer (score 7):

You should use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) otherwise Python interprets the user input as variables (that's why you're getting `name 'yes' is not defined`).

Furthermore, you shouldn't use `raw_input()` as default parameter value as this is evaluated whenever Python loads the module.

Consider the following:

```
def the_flying_circus(Question=None):
    if Question is None:
        Question = raw_input("Do you like the Flying Circus?")
    if Question == 'yes':
        print "That's great!" 
    elif Question == 'no':
        print "That's too bad!"
```

Although, I have to say, it's not entirely clear what purpose the above function has because `Question` can now be both a question and the user's answer. How about passing in the question as a string and assigning the result to `Answer`?

```
def the_flying_circus(Question):
    Answer = raw_input(Question)
    if Answer == 'yes':
        print "That's great!" 
    elif Answer == 'no':
        print "That's too bad!"
```

Lastly, variable names in Python are written without capitals at the beginning so the code would become:

```
def the_flying_circus(question):
    answer = raw_input(question)
    if answer == 'yes':
        print "That's great!" 
    elif answer == 'no':
        print "That's too bad!"
```

Comment: I SEE! Thank you so much. Pass Question as a str and assign the result to answer. That's sorta what I wanted to do but I just didn't conceptualize it right. Total noob.

Comment: `if not Question` is preferred idiom to `if Question is None`

Comment: and the variable should be named `question` to be PEP-8 compliant

Comment: @smci: `if not Question` and `if Question is None` are not equivalent so you can't always use either of them. Also, I adapted the code as written in the question - it's not always useful to teach people about additional stuff, such as PEP8, when you're starting to learn Python.